# Linux Terminal emulator with separate input area and output area?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, ncurses

I am looking for any terminal emulator (if any out there), which will have 2 separate areas for input commands and output area.

Terminal Emulator

```
 Output
    more output
    more output still...

    blah blahh
    blaahh blah
    words
=================================================
>input here
```

I tried to search in Google but found nothing useful, also I read somewhere this can be achieved using ncurses library, but I have no idea how this can be done. Also I feel, somebody must have done this before, if anyone has done this kind of thing, please share your solution with me, or anyone who knows how this can be done, then I would be grateful if you can provide me some pointers to achieve this.

Comment: Are you asking if there exists such a thing already, or how to implement one?

Comment: @awoodland, ya I would like to know if anything like that already exists, and if not then some info on how to start implementing it.

Comment: @n.m. actually admins have problems while monitoring logs in server, to make sure they dont loose important information, and separate the input commands from the long running output screen, also to create a new kind of terminal experience :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simulate such behaviour with any terminal, by open two instances of it. At terminal #2, get the current PTS by:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/10 # for example
```

then, on terminal #1 you type:

```
$ exec &> /dev/pts/10
$ echo you can see this message on terminal \#2
$ echo this is also true for standard error > /dev/stderr
```

Comment: I'm using RHEL6.  I'm not sure why I saw different behavior; with both `gnome-terminal` and `xterm`, after `exec &> /dev/pts/XX` the terminal stopped echoing back text.  However, this worked: `exec &> >(tee /dev/pts/XX)`